# Counting number of .csv files infolder

Tags: r

I'm very new to R and am trying to count the number of .csv files there are in a folder.  I have created the following code:

```
DATA <- "C:/Users/Stacey/Documents/R/Proj/RawDatabase/"

countFilesInDirectory <- function(strPathToDirectory, arrExtensions) {
  intFileCount = 0;
  arrFiles = scandir(strPathToDirectory);
  foreach(arrFiles as strFile) {

    if(is_dir("strPathToDirectory/strFile") && is_readable("strPathToDirectory/strFile")) {
      intFileCount += countFilesInDirectory("strPathToDirectory/strFile", arrExtensions);
    } 

  }

  return intFileCount;
}


intFileCount = countFilesInDirectory(DATA, array('csv'));
echo intFileCount
```

but I get the following error output:

```
> DATA <- "C:/Users/Stacey/Documents/R/Proj/RawDatabase/"
> 
> countFilesInDirectory <- function(strPathToDirectory, arrExtensions) {
+   intFileCount = 0;
+   arrFiles = scandir(strPathToDirectory);
+   foreach(arrFiles as strFile) {
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"  arrFiles = scandir(strPathToDirectory);
  foreach(arrFiles as"
>     
>     if(is_dir("strPathToDirectory/strFile") && is_readable("strPathToDirectory/strFile")) {
+       intFileCount += countFilesInDirectory("strPathToDirectory/strFile", arrExtensions);
Error: unexpected '=' in:
"    if(is_dir("strPathToDirectory/strFile") && is_readable("strPathToDirectory/strFile")) {
      intFileCount +="
>     } 
Error: unexpected '}' in "    }"
>     
>   }
Error: unexpected '}' in "  }"
>   
>   return intFileCount;
Error: unexpected symbol in "  return intFileCount"
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
> 
> 
> intFileCount = countFilesInDirectory(DATA, array('csv'));
Error: could not find function "countFilesInDirectory"
> echo intFileCount
Error: unexpected symbol in "echo intFileCount"
```

Comment: Are you trying to write R? Because `foreach` isn't a base R keyword and `as` is a function used for coercion, not part of any looping syntax. Are you using the `foreach` package?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot: `length(list.files("path/to/the/folder",pattern="*.csv"))`

ps: no need for semi-colons at each EOL

Comment: Might want to add `recursive=TRUE` to get the same behavior as the proposed function.

Comment: Thanks, this may be a dumb question from a newbie but how to I output to the console say I have intFileCount = length(list.files("path/to/the/folder",pattern="*.csv")) can I say echo intFileCount ?

Comment: use the "()" , thus (length(list.files("path/to/the/folder",pattern="*.csv"))) or simply cat(intFileCount)

Comment: when I try to use: intFileCount <- length(list.files("C:/Users/Stacey/Documents/R/Proj/RawDatabase",pattern="*.csv")
print(intFileCount)  I get the error: Error: unexpected symbol in:
"intFileCount <- length(list.files("C:/Users/Stacey/Documents/R/Proj/RawDatabase",pattern="*.csv")
print  and I can't figure out what the unexpected symbol is...

Comment: rename the folder "RawDatab‌​ase" ;) . also use semicolon between commands that are found in the same line.